# How do I bypass redirect in Shopify if I want to develop on a theme?

Tags: geolocation, shopify

I'm trying to setup work on a client website which is in Shopify. They are in the US, I am in the UK. I'm trying to bypass a redirect so I can work on the US site from the UK.

The site uses Geolizr

Does anyone have a clue? Other than using a VPN?

Chrome, Firefox, IE extension to hide geo-location.

It still redirects.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how comfortable you are with Chrome devtools, but --

This is a generic answer to a common problem of making a script not run on a site when you *just need to get something done*.

1. Open a new blank tab in chrome and then open devtools and [go to the network tab](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/)
2. Check the "preserve log" or *tick* as you brits call it.  weirdos ;]
3. Navigate to the site and the network log will will up
4. Look for requests from geolizr and identify the domain name they're using.  ex: "js.geolizr.example"
5. Open your **hosts file** (this location varies depending on mac/linux/windows.  see blow for details)
6. Add a new entry for `127.0.0.1 js.geolizr.example`. save.

Now when you visit the site, all requests for the geolizr code will not leave your computer (and will 404/timeout).

This method is also useful if you want to test modifications to a script running on a live site.

Hosts file locations:

- Mac: Open terminal and do `sudo vi /private/etc/hosts`
- Windows: C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts